# How to print remote url using ionic-cordova?

Tags: ionic-framework, printing

I need to print a remote webpage using ionic.

I am stuck in printing a bill which is remotely available as html

please help

highly appreciated your help

Comment: I find this for plugin print : https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer

Comment: does it work with ionic version 4.2? Also can I print remote web page content with it?